# Is it possible to edit file details of multiple files at once? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, file, command-line

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the file details, in this case of music files (Title, Artists, Track #, etc) of more than one file at once, or in rapid succession with a batch file or command of some kind, instead of changing each individually through the properties window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Mp3tag](http://portableapps.com/node/18890) you can do all kinds on activity you have mentioned..
Its Portable too..!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot. Just out of curiosity however, is it possible to do this in command line?

Comment: @user2177874: Yes its possible..!

Comment: Not running on windows 10, if you have any latest link that can help us out. Please share

Comment: I am currently using in windows 10 only. it works fine you can also download from microsoft store. 
https://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found a helpful website:
http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Most flexible way is via command prompt and a command similar to this:
ren *.html *.txt